# HTML5 semantic elements: share/like buttons in footer

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have some share/like buttons as well as my Google+ profile icon.

Is it correct to put them in the `footer` element at the bottom of my page?

Comment: If you want it in your footer it's correct

Comment: are you talking about javascript here or just layout aesthetics?

Comment: I wonder if the `footer` element is semantic for my content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/sections.html#the-footer-element) is appropriate for such links.

It’s a pretty easy decision, as such links are clearly not part of a section’s main content, so there is only `footer` or [`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/sections.html#the-header-element) left as possible candidates. And here the definition of `footer` seems to come closer (emphasis mine):

> […] typically contains information about its section such as **who wrote it**, links to **related documents**, copyright data, and the like.

#### Share/like links

When the share/like links are for sharing/liking the article (e.g. in case of a blog post), use the `footer` of the `article` section.

When the share/like links are for sharing/liking the whole website, use the `footer` of the `body` sectioning root.

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <footer><!-- for links applying to this article --></footer>
  </article>
  <footer><!-- for links applying to the whole page resp. site --></footer>
</body>
```

#### Profile links

In case where the author of the article is a different person than the author of the page/website, place the profile links accordingly.

If the linked profile offers a way to contact you, you might use an [`address` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/sections.html#the-address-element) in addition.

```
<footer>
  <address><a>…</a></address>
</footer>
```

You may want to use the [`author` resp. `publisher` link type](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55536/17633).